# How to increment a passed enum in a function?

Tags: enums, mql4

I'm passing an *enum* to a function. In this function I want to increment the passed enum with some integer steps. I though this would be possible since an *enum* is supposedly an integer by definition. But for some reason the following doesn't work.

Here's my relevant code:

```cpp
enum THE_ENUM {
    S3,
    S4,
    S5,
    ...
};

double getPrice(THE_ENUM level) {
    switch (level) {
        case S3 : return mml[S3];
        case S4 : return mml[S4];
        case S5 : return mml[S5];
        ...
    }
    ...
}

int placeOrder(THE_ENUM tPL) {
    ...
    price = getPrice(S4);     // this works
    price = getPrice(tPL);    // this works
    price = getPrice(tPL+2);  // this doesn't!
    ...
}
...
placeOrder(S3);
...
```

**How can I use the passed enum to access the next or previous one, as first defined?**

Comment: Enums are constants, right? Maybe my understanding is not correct.

Comment: Your compiler appears to be badly configured. The posted code is invalid C.

Comment: The compiler is fine, it is the *Metatrader4* compiler which is using a variant of C++. Ok, so they are constant integers. So how can I access `S5` value, by using something like `getPrice(S4 + 1)`?

Comment: If you intend to increment a value or do any other arithmetic on it, then enums were the wrong choice. Enums are for situations in which you want a few readable identifieres, which only need to be of different values. If you have assumptions on their values, then use integers.

Comment: I think we might be looking at a XY problem. Please study the concept and try to see how the description maps to your problem. X: You want to do math on enums in order to solve Y: ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "it is the Metatrader4 compiler which is using a variant of C++" @not2qubit then the [c] tag is erroneous!

Comment: Ok, I have no idea how to classify it, but it is `> C` and `< C++`. Anyway, if you can do this in any of these languages, I'm sure it will also work here.

Comment: This isn't c or c++, this is mql4, so tagging it as c will only harm you. The languages are NOT similar enough. Also, enums are implemented as integers, but won't always act that way. What you are asking is most likely impossible, but I don't know mql enough to tell you for sure.

Comment: `S4 + 1` works if you know the enums are sequential. If it matters to you, you can implement an enum iterator for yourself.

Comment: What do you expect `tPL + 2` to do if `tPL` is already the last enum?

Comment: Obviously the `...` indicates that all items are present. How would you make your own iterator? -- Ok, so everybody has an opinion, but nobody has a working code snippet?

Comment: in c [what you describe](https://ideone.com/fkHy3T) works.

Comment: You can use X-macros to use a single macro to represent all the enum elements, and then also build a table to derive the successor of each enum. It is not entirely clear what your end game is, hence it is hard to suggest solutions. No one wants to offer you something that won't solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FACT : `MQL4` is not a compiled C-lang

> <sub>Data of the enum type belong to a certain limited set of data. Defining the enumeration type:</sub>
>
> *`enum name of enumerable type`*
>     `{`
>     `list of values`
>     `};`
>
> <sub>The list of values is a list of identifiers of named constants separated by commas.
>   After the enumeration is declared, a new integer-valued 4-byte data type appears. Declaration of the new data type allows the compiler to strictly control types of passed parameters, because enumeration introduces new named constants. In the above example, the January named constant has the value of 0, February - 1, December - 11.
>   
>
>
>   **Rule:** If a certain value is not assigned to a named constant that is a member of the enumeration, its new value will be formed automatically. If it is the first member of the enumeration, the 0 value will be assigned to it. For all subsequent members, values will be calculated based on the value of the previous members by adding one.
>   
>
>
>   **Example:**</sub>

```
enum intervals      // Enumeration of named constants
   {
    month      =  1, // Interval of one month       ---- code-assogned =  1
    two_months,      // Two months                  ---- auto-assigned  ~ 2
    quarter,         // Three months - a quarter    ---- auto-assigned  ~ 3
    halfyear   =  6, // Half a year                 ---- CODE-assigned =  6
    year       = 12, // Year - 12 months            ---- CODE-assigned = 12
    wild13,          //        13 months            ---- auto-assigned  ~13
    decade     =120  // Decade                      ---- CODE-assigned =120
   };
```

This means, the wish-to-have, compiler-assisted, **`enum`**-value "***arithmetics***" ( asking for having a chance to call an on-the-fly evaluated/decoded in **`getPrice(`** "***second-value-before-wild13***" **`)`** is possible, yet do not expect it to be a battery-included, low-hanging fruit ready to be available from the MQL4-language architects, that have optimised the compiled-language code for efficiency and minimum latency.

One may implement one's own arithmetic for `MQL4-enum`-s, as the price-level `double getPrice( smart_ENUM aLevelCONST )` mapper above strives to implement, yet the costs of developing such a design, using a restricted language beyond its limits, are on one's own consideration ( do not forget a few years back surprise, when **`string`**-s ceased to be `string`-s and suddenly, without either a prior or ex-post notice, they silently become **`struct`**-s - each Fund Manager, Trader, Support Team member or API-maintainer can imagine the shock and nightmare, once things turned wreck havoc without a chance to understand why ( the `string` -> `struct` notice was but in a next release of a Help-file for MQL4/MetaEditor ... too many hairs went off, countless funds went evaporated till the root-cause of the crashed factories was found hidden in a tangential notice in the Help-file and the "change" was re-factored back into the API-re-design ... **We better do not expose one selves to a similarly un-manageable risk** or rather do not play wild with similar "dependencies" on a moving sands territory )

At least, you've been warned **:o)**

> **Notes :**
>
> - Unlike C++, the size of the internal representation of the enumerated type in MQL4 is always equal to 4 bytes. That is, *`sizeof( months )`* returns the value 4.
> - Unlike C++, an anonymous enumeration can't be declared in MQL4. That is, a unique name must be always specified after the *`enum`* keyword.

Comment: Any ideas for a work-around or better solution to do the same?